# Getting someone's last picture on behalf of the server

Tags: php, oauth, instagram

Hi guys I understand how to retrieve the ACCESS TOKEN by requesting the permission to access a client's instagram but I'm trying to avoid exactly that.

I need to be able to get someone's last picture without requesting to authenticate on instagram to the client.

There has to be a way with the api to fetch that picture while using OUR instagram account and not the client's instagram is there not?

I don't want to have to hard code a connection and html scraping!

Please enlighten me and sorry for my bad english!

TL;DR: I want to use my client id, client secret or username/password of my instagram account to view another user on instagram's picture!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your access_token to access other user's instagram photo feed API. As long as that user is not private. You cannot use client_id for accessing any user information, you have to authenticate and use access_token. This API call will work for, just replace the user_id you want to access and use your access_token.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER_ID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```